# Missing files in mod_pagespeed - how do I find where they were requested?

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

Looking at my apache error logs i'm seeing a lot of 404 errors for resources such as JS & CSS.

**For example:**
`[Tue Feb 21 14:41:58 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.21.2-1381 @7107] Fetch failed for http://www.example.com/scripts/scripts/jquery.something.CUSTOM.js.pagespeed.jm.tEOVuEyXGC.js, status=404`

The resource it's *SHOULD* load is located at `http://www.example.com/scripts/jquery.something.CUSTOM.js.pagespeed.jm.tEOVuEyXGC.js`.

Unfortunately I can't find the section of my site that is responsible for trying to load the incorrect path.

Any ideas how I can add this to the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit a bug with more details at http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list or email https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss to discuss.

It looks like some sort of base URL problem. But I haven't seen this particular type of problem before.

-Shawn (mod_pagespeed team)